# Disable vi from going to the last visited line upon file opening

Tags: vim, vi

Is there something I can put in my `exrc` file to prevent `vi` from going to the last line I was on last time I had the file open and just set the cursor at the top by default?

I think it is distro-specific -- it doesn't behave like that on Solaris but does on RHEL.

Answer (score 8):

This feature is implemented as autocommand. It is set up in `/etc/vimrc` - see snippet below. Remove it from there or add command to remove that autocommand to your vimrc file. (I am using fedora - on rhel it should be very similar)

```
if has("autocmd")
  augroup fedora
  autocmd!
  "...
  " When editing a file, always jump to the last cursor position
  autocmd BufReadPost *
  \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") <= line("$") |
  \   exe "normal! g'\"" |
  \ endif
  "...
  augroup END
endif
```

If you do not have permissions or do not want to change `/etc/vimrc`, the command to put in your local `.vimrc` to remove the autocommand is 
`:au! <group> <cmdname>`, in this case `:au! fedora BufReadPost`.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but this doesn't work for me on RHEL. I put in `au! redhat BufReadPost` in my `~/.vimrc` but it still set the cursor location to the last position. Eventually, I just put a `call cursor(1,1)` to force the cursor to be at the start of the file.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a comment than a real answer. Solaris is not a Linux distro. It is a version of Unix operating system. vi on RedHat which is a Linux distro (Linux != Unix) is symbolically linked to vim. Solaris vi refers to  genuine vi editor created by Bill Joy. So we are not talking here about the same editors. I have no idea how vim behaves as I am using nvi on my OpenBSD box which is another clone of genuine vi. I would suggest that you install [vi editor](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/) on your RedHat box first and try to reproduce the problem. Typing `vi filename.txt`
should open the file and put the prompt at the begging of the first line. Typing `vi + filename.txt` should open file in the last line. However vi can be open with many other options like `vi +n filename.txt` which puts you at the beginning of n-th line or `vi +/regexp filename.txt` which puts you at the beginning of the line which contains first occurrence of the regular expression (regexp), `view filename.txt` read only mode. Please refer to the man pages for the complete list. Do not forget to unlink vi command from vim when you install the real **vi**.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some other option available for this, but you can use the following work around

```
vim <filename> +1
```

`+1` indicates, to move the cursor to line 1.

Comment: i got `line    2:
E682: Invalid search pattern or delimiter` when i put just `vim +1` in my .exrc -- i don't want to have to specify a file, i.e. i want it applied to ANY file

Comment: same with `vim * +1`

Comment: It is a option to be entered at command-line and not a one to put in `vimrc` file. As mentioned this is a work around.

Comment: I think it is distro-specific -- it doesn't behave like that on Solaris but does on RHEL

Answer (score 0):

To make sure, that this function is added by a plugin try to open the file with

```
vim --noplugin <filename>
```

If the cursor doesn't jump to the position of the last edit you should open the file again without the `--noplugin`-switch and study the output of `:scriptnames`. `:scriptnames` lists all previously sourced scripts.

If you are a semi-experienced vim user you can exclude most of the scripts by means of the path. For instance, all scripts located under `&rtp/{ftplugin,spell,colors,syntax}` (&rtp := runtimepath) are out of question.

I can imagine, that the script which implements this feature has a related name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the opposite problem and got here as a result. I was wondering why my cursor would go back to the top of the file. I'm used to switching between buffers and having to find my position each time would not be efficient at all!

None of the answers here speak of the problem, so I thought I would add my own answer, because that would solve your problem. All I have to do is add a C or C++ comment on the first line after a space! I don't know whether this is expected to be a feature or a bug, but well... the cursor comes right back at the top in that case.

```
+---- see the space here?
|
v
 // first line of file
```

Removing the comment or the space *fixes my problem*.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the solution posted by otokan for several years until it stopped working recently.  I found a new solution posted at the following site:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/905074/how-can-i-disable-vim-jump-to-last-position-feature-in-ubuntu-17-04

There are two solutions posted at the above link:

Solution 1: In the file /usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim, find the autocmd that enables this behavior, and comment it out.  This autocmd looks as follows:

```
" When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
" Don't do it when the position is invalid, when inside an event handler
" (happens when dropping a file on gvim) and for a commit message (it's
" likely a different one than last time).
autocmd BufReadPost *
  \ if line("'\"") >= 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") && &ft !~# 'commit'
  \ |   exe "normal! g`\""
  \ | endif
```

On my system (Crux 3.5 Linux), the autocmd was actually in the file /usr/share/vim/defaults.vim (no "vim80" subdirectory), so you may need to search around under /usr/share/vim for the defaults.vim file that defines this autocmd.

Solution 2: Add the following line to your .vimrc file:

```
:augroup vimStartup | au! | augroup END
```

I am currently using solution 2.

Comment: Within Vim, use `echo $VIMRUNTIME` to see the actual runtime directory. You don't need to search for it.